# Emacs CEDET semantic-ia-fast-jump gives error

Tags: emacs, cedet

I am getting the following  error  message when I use `semantic-ia-fast-jump` with CEDET.

```
Lisp nesting exceeds 'max-lisp-eval-depth'.
```

This is for a C project. I am using GTAGS along with CEDET.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem was due to the c snippet:

```
typedef struct _foo {
    int bar;
} foo, *pfoo;
```

it went away with

```
typedef struct _foo {
    int bar;
} foo;
typedef foo *pfoo;
```

Answer (score 0):

That likely mean, some where, the code is going for infinite loop (eval,apply). IIUC Emacs puts a precautionary limit about 600 (by default).

Two things you can do.
one is increase the that variable limit and try again.

investigate where and which function is causing that that.
`(setq debug-on-error t)`